# While assigning a function to a variable in JS, why does it gets executed automatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object

I come from Python background, and partially understand the concept of functions being the first class objects in python and javascript.

But this behaviour looks unusual to me:

```
$ node
> function calc(){console.log('hey');};
> var a = calc()
hey
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `()` in your sample [var a = calc();] means you want to invoke the function.

If you want to assign the function to a variable you should do -

```
var a = calc;
```

then, if you want to invoke it you can use

```
a();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only with

```
function calc() {
    console.log('hey');
};
var a = calc;
a(); // hey
```